# Python 3.2 script to connect to local MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I am running an Ubuntu Server. I would like for it to have a Python (v3.2) CGI script that would connect, and run a query, to the local MySQL database I have set up. Currently, the only things I found don't support Python 3.2. Please do not suggest switching to an earlier version of Python, because that is not an option for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**[pymysql](https://code.google.com/p/pymysql/) - Pure Python MySQL client** is very good.
It works with Python 3.x, and doesn't have any dependencies.

> This pure Python MySQL client provides a DB-API to a MySQL database by talking directly to the server via the binary client/server protocol.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> import pymysql
> conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', unix_socket='/tmp/mysql.sock', user='root', passwd=None, db='mysql')
> cur = conn.cursor()
> cur.execute("SELECT Host,User FROM user")
> for r in cur:
>     print(r)
> cur.close()
> conn.close()
> ```

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I never saw that :)

Answer (score 2):

[sqlalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) supports MySQL and [all versions of Python 3](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/intro.html#installation). It's nice because you don't have to write SQL; it makes tables look like classes and records look like objects.

Answer (score 1):

BlaXpirit's answer above to use pymysql works great! But one small caveat. The link to pymysql in his comment will take you to https://github.com/petehunt/PyMySQL/ which is for python 2.x. If you are using python 3, you want to download and install pymysql3 (version 3.0.5 as of 5/12/12) from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyMySQL3/