# Python 3.2 script to connect to local MySQL database

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, python

I am running an Ubuntu Server. I would like for it to have a Python (v3.2) CGI script that would connect, and run a query, to the local MySQL database I have set up. Currently, the only things I found don't support Python 3.2. Please do not suggest switching to an earlier version of Python, because that is not an option for me.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Probably better to have this question migrated to StackOverflow where programmers can look at it. If it's voted to move, it will automatically migrate, so you don't have to repost the question or anything.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tip. I will repost to StackOverflow, because I don't have much time to finish working on the above problem.

Comment: You probably shouldn't. You could go to the chat room "vote to close" and post the link to this question there and they'll migrate it for you, or flag this for moderator attention.

Comment: I flagged it for you. This will prevent duplicates from floating around.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562691/python-3-2-script-to-connect-to-local-mysql-database/6562810), right down to the wording. It even gave me deja vu.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this previous question: [MySQL-db lib for Python 3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384471/mysql-db-lib-for-python-3-0)

Seems that a python 3 option is available.

Comment: Actually, I found that question while I was searching for an author. However, none of those options worked, and I couldn't find a different solution.