# Connect to a .sql database hosted on Google Drive via Colab Notebook

Tags: python, mysql, google-colaboratory

I am using a Colab Notebook with Jupyter's `%load_ext sql` magic keyword enabled to directly use SQL commands in Jupyter. Currently, I remote into a database I host on a server in order to demonstrate SQL commands to students. However, I'd like to host the `.sql` file "locally" via Google Drive and connect to that shared file in order to obviate the need to actually host the file on a server.

How would I go about doing this? I have seen answers like this: [Python 3.2 script to connect to local MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562691/python-3-2-script-to-connect-to-local-mysql-database), but it assumes that the file is hosted locally, and not via GDrive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways I know of to use your Google Drive in Colab:

1. Mount it with python

```py
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Follow the instructions in the output of the cell

-- or ---

2. Use the Colab gui to mount the drive (click here red circle then the refresh folder button):

[image]

You will then be able to access your `.sql` query file as text and execute at `/content/drive/.../some_query.sql` You should see the  `drive` folder in the `Files` gui

The full code to access and query a sql file hosted in drive might be this (but I would be most worried about connecting to your database, especially if it is hosted on your local machine, if its in the cloud then you're probably fine):

```py
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

# %%

def open_text(path: str) -> str:
    with open(path, 'r') as file:
        return file.read()

# open the query file
query = open_text('./drive/My Drive/.../some_query.sql')

# %%

import pymysql
conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', unix_socket='/tmp/mysql.sock', user='root', passwd=None, db='mysql')
cur = conn.cursor()
# execute the query
cur.execute(query)
for r in cur:
    print(r)
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Sorry — I should have been more clear. It’s not the mounting and accessing the file that was challenging. It’s referencing the mounted file in a Jupyter notebook so that I can use ordinary SQL commands on it.

Comment: @Parseltongue I think the last part of the answer may have answered your question but I updated it with the code to connect and query. Are you by chance using sqlite (probably should have asked that earlier)? In which case this should still work, you just connect to the sqlite database through the drive path like any normal file.

Comment: Thanks so much for this thorough answer! I really appreciate it. I'm currently getting the error: "OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' ([Errno 2] No such file or directory)")" on the line where you set the value of `conn = pymysql.connect...`.  Any thoughts? This was the same problem I was having

Comment: No problem! It looks like python can't find your database (in this case a mysql server, I just copied the code from the link in your question). What type of database are you using? If you're using a mysql server hosted on your local machine, you can't easily connect to it from Colab unless you open some ports, if you're using sqlite ("portable" database files) it will be easier and you want to use sqlite library instead